# asp.net mvc content folder is public even using form authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a MVC application with form authentication, I tested it works fine when I try to access a controller url, it redirects me to the login page, however I found the file in content folder can be accessed without login, why? is it the nature of MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I am answering myself, I have this in my web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
```

which means all static content files, e.g. image,html, will not go through asp.net pipeline and will bypass the authorize role setting

Answer (score -1):

To resolve put this in to web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi the code you provided is without any explanation. Please provide any explanation for the code, otherwise it would be not helpful to anyone. Refer to the guide on how to anwser here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer